# What is Leiningen in relation to Maven?

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

I mean, does Leiningen delegate to Maven when managing lifecycle?
For reference, I know close to nothing about clojure yet.

Comment: What does lifecycle refer to here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leiningen uses Maven's libraries for [managing dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/) via [Pomegranate library](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate). Lifecycle itself is implemented in Leiningen itself.